# Implementing javascript with dependencies in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm migrating an application from AngularJS to Angular 6. The application uses `Raphael`, a javascript library.

I installed `Raphael` with npm and imported the library in the Angular module with

`import * as Raphael from 'raphael/raphael';`

This works fine, however I also need a related javascript file called `raphael-ellipsis.js` that has a dependency on `Raphael` declaration. I added `raphael-ellipsis.js` to `angular.json` in the `scripts` section but I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined`

This is because `Raphael` is installed in `node_modules` and `raphael-ellipsis.js` is not aware of it. How to fix this problem?

Comment: import `Raphael` into your `angular.json` file ?

Comment: you mean to touch a minimized file that I didn't author?

Comment: Yes ? I remember using mermaidJS to draw charts, I had to do that.

Comment: ps0604 I think you should just import Raphael first, and then import the Raphael-ellipsis. I dont see why it would give you any problems if you do it like that. its how I did it for pouchdb as well

Comment: @trichetriche I tried adding to the js file `import { Raphael } from '../node_modules/raphael/raphael';` but I'm getting `Unexpected token {`, how did you add it to mermaid?

Comment: @enf0rcer I installed Raphael with npm, so it's in node_modules, the other file raphael-ellipsis I added manually to `angular.json`, how to import `Raphael` first?

Comment: In `angular.json` file, not in the component.

Comment: thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in webpack.config.js (in both devConfig and envConfig)

*new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Raphael: 'raphael' })*

(for Ionic 3, it is in node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js)

Or in angular.json in *scripts[]*

```
"build": {
    ....
    "scripts": ["./node_modules/raphael/raphael.js"]
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `webpack.config.js` file (I'm using Angular 6). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit above about angular.json. I just tested, it works :-)

Comment: I'm getting an error, this is how import the auxiliary library; `import from 'raphael-ellipsis.min.js';` but when I try to use one of the functions it fails because it doesn't find it.

Comment: I also tried `import * from 'raphael-ellipsis.min.js';` but it fails with the same error. [This is what I'm trying to import](https://github.com/olegskl/fitText/blob/master/raphael.fitText.js).

Comment: Also tried `import * as fitText from 'raphael-ellipsis.min.js';` with no luck. This is the error I get in all cases: `fitText is not a function`

Comment: you do not need to import it, just add in scripts

Comment: no luck, I added both Raphael and raphael-ellipsis.min.js to scripts but still get `fitText is not a function`